# Multiple hierarchy of task

Tags: c#, multithreading

I want to call a task which itself call a async method which inturn returna bool value.
I want to do something on the basis of that outcome.
I can get the data on `outcome.Result.Result` but this does not look good and I wish to have the output in `outcome.Result`.

I  can not figure it out.
Can someone please guide.

```
private void OnValidated(ValidatedIntergrationEvent evt)
            {

                var outcome=Task.Factory.StartNew(() => mydata.UpdateValidated());
                if (outcome.Result.Result)//This work fine but I think I need something to do so that outcome.Result gives my solution.
                { }
                else { }

            }


      public async  Task<bool> UpdateValidated()
            {
               var result= await  Mediator.Send(new ValidatedEvent(this));
               return result;        

            }
 public async Task<bool> Handle(ValidatedEvent notification, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {            //dO WORK 
            // return Task.FromResult(true);
           return true;

        }
```

Comment: Don’t use `Task.Factory.StartNew` to start a new task that runs your task. Just call `UpdateValidated()` directly. Also, try to avoid using `.Result`. Make your code fully asynchronous instead.

Comment: If I remove Task.Factory.StartNew.,will it be still  async .I want it in thread so it does not block anythinbg

Comment: You are calling an asynchronous method, so yeah, that will be asynchronous. If you want to force it on a new thread, you could start a new task, but then the task itself should be async (`Task.Run(async () => await myData.UpdateValidated())`)

Comment: Thanks  a lot.But I can not accept the answer as it is in comment.Also,can you explain a bit why my code was wrong

Comment: For future reference, your code is hard to read now because of mangled indentation. Do practice a little with the `{}` button. It is easy to do right, and that makes more people read it.

Comment: @poke @bommelding-Sure.I will keep in mind. @Poke Also,what is wrong in my code.I understand poke suggestion but could not get why mine is wrong.I tried `var outcome = Task.Run(()=>InsuranceCompany.UpdateValidated());` also compiles properly.Can you explain a bit please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `UpdateValidated` is already asynchronous, you should just call it directly to execute it. Things like `Task.Factory.StartNew` or `Task.Run` offer a way to put *synchronous* tasks on a new thread so that they can run asynchronously. So you should just call it directly:

```
private void OnValidated(ValidatedIntergrationEvent evt)
{
    var outcome = mydata.UpdateValidated()

    // Note: this WILL block, regardless of how you call the async function
    var result = outcome.Result;
}
```

You should try to avoid using `.Result` though, as this will block synchronous functions until the asynchronous result is ready, and may even cause deadlocks. If the `OnValidated` is a standard event handler, you *could* make it asynchronous instead and await your task:

```
private async void OnValidated(ValidatedIntergrationEvent evt)
{
    var result = await mydata.UpdateValidated()
}
```

But this make this event handler fire and forget which can be dangerous. So you should really try to change your code that you are truly running asynchronously when calling asynchronous code.

Finally, note that you *can* force the asynchronous task onto a separate thread using `Task.Run`. This is useful when the asynchronous call also does a lot on the CPU:

```
var outcome = Task.Run(() => mydata.UpdateValidated());
```

This looks very similar to your `Task.Factory.StartNew()` call but returns only a `Task<bool>` instead of your `Task<Task<bool>>`. This is because `Task.Run` has an overload that explicitly allows you to call asynchronous methods which makes `Task.Run` just pass on the result.